# How to handle two javascript events?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to do some validation check to the password field a form. I am calling a function `onkeypress` to check whether capsLock is on or off then `onblur` function check the password field value. But as I enter any value in the password field, the onblur runs immediately along with onkeypress. This defeats my purpose of checking the capslock and then the field value.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" size=50 name="password" value="" onkeypress="checkCapsLock(event);" onblur="chkPsw(this.value);">
```

JavaScript:

```
function chkPsw(inpsw){
    var psw = inpsw.toLowerCase(inpsw);
    psw = trim(psw);
    if (psw.length<4 || psw.length>15){
        alert ('password length can be min. 4 and max. 15 chars' );
        return false;
    }
    var p1=/^[a-z0-9_\-\!\@\$\%\&\(\)\{\}\[\]\<\>]+$/;/* a-z 0-9 _ - ! @ $ % & ( ) { } [ ] < > */
    if(p1.test(psw)) {
        alert("The password:::: "+psw+" :::: is ok.");
        return true;
    } else {
        var p2 = /\s+/;
        if (p2.test(psw)){
            alert(psw+" is not ok. Space is not allowed.");
            return false;
        } else{
            alert(psw+"\n is not ok only a-z 0-9 _ - ! @ $ % & ( ) { } [ ] < > ");
            return false;
        }
    }
}


function checkCapsLock( e ) {
    var myKeyCode=0;
    var myShiftKey=false;
    var myMsg='Caps Lock is On.\n\nTo prevent entering your password incorrectly,\nyou should press Caps Lock to turn it off.';

    // Internet Explorer 4+
    if ( document.all ) {
        myKeyCode=e.keyCode;
        myShiftKey=e.shiftKey;
    }

    if ( ( myKeyCode >= 65 && myKeyCode <= 90 ) && !myShiftKey ) {
        alert( myMsg );
        return false;
    } else if ( ( myKeyCode >= 97 && myKeyCode <= 122 ) && myShiftKey ) {
        alert( myMsg );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think I made myself clear. If any one can help me that would be great.

What I want is when someone starts typing in this password field the status of capsLock is checked and told to the user and then when the complete field is filled out and the user moves to next field, the password value is checked.

Comment: @Rahul The first couple of lines are not properly indented. Could you fix that?

Comment: You should really consider using a JavaScript library, http://jquery.com/. Netscape 4/6 and IE 4? Who could possibly be using that?!

Comment: @AmitG it's probably copy-pasta.

Comment: @Rahul Utb: I wonder who voted this down, seems like a fine question to me. However, I can't reproduce the error, I don't see the onblur running when I type http://jsfiddle.net/Gx4mQ/

Comment: @Vivin Agreed. @Juan I tried fixing up his code, jsFiddle though, is choking on it.

Comment: @Amit G: It only chokes when you blur off the field, because trim is not defined. It does properly show the alert when I type and Caps Lock is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're using alert boxes to notify the user (bad practice, and annoying) which results in the password field losing focus.

The solution? Use a boolean condition,

Here's a jQuery example (I'm cleaning up your code),

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MnMps/

```
jQuery.fn.caps = function(cb){
    return this.keypress(function(e){
        var w = e.which ? e.which : (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : -1);
        var s = e.shiftKey ? e.shiftKey : (e.modifiers ? !!(e.modifiers & 4) : false);
        var c = ((w >= 65 && w <= 90) && !s) || ((w >= 97 && w <= 122) && s);
        cb.call(this, c);
    });
};

var alerting = false;

$('#password').caps(function(caps){
    if(caps){
        alerting = true;
        alert('Unintentional uppercase leads to wars!');
       }
});

$('#password').blur(function() {
    if(alerting == false && !this.value.match(/^[a-z0-9_\-\!\@\$\%\&\(\)\{\}\[\]\<\>]+$/)) {
        alert("Abort! Invalid character detected!");
    }
    alerting = false;
});
```

**PS:** Props to capslock detection, http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caps-lock

**EDIT:** Gave up on cleaning up your code.